Unable to Fetch Data from Node.js Server on Devices Other Than Hosting Device
I'm encountering an issue where I can't establish a connection to my server from devices other than the one hosting the server. The server is running locally, and I'm developing a web application using React as the frontend.
When I access the application from the hosting device (e.g., my laptop), everything works fine. However, when attempting to access the same application from other devices on the same network (i've tried with both iPhones and Androids), I'm unable to fetch data from the server. I can get to the page but there no data being loaded, (From Mac (Hosting Device)From Other Device Same Network.
Upon inspecting the network activity using the web inspector, I noticed that all the failed requests have a type of "fetch" and a domain of "localhost". On the other hand, successful requests, have types like "txt", "js", "document", "socket", etc., with the domain being my IP address.
I've checked my CORS configuration, and it seems to allow requests from any origin. Additionally, I've ensured that the server is running and accessible from the client devices by trying to access it directly through a web browser.
More things I have tried:

Verified that both my Mac and iPhone are connected to the same Wi-Fi network.
Disabled firewall restrictions on my Mac, all incoming connections are allowed.
Confirmed that the server is configured to allow CORS from all origins (Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *).
Tested accessing the server from phones using different web browsers

I expected the data to load successfully like when accessing it from the host device.

I'm not sure if I'm understanding correctly but, from what I see, you can connect to your app from other devices, but in the network calls, it says localhost/api/data (a fetch to an api) and it doesnt work / returns 404? If that is the case and in the network call you see "Localhost" then is it possible that in your env or wherever you have your string to fetch the data you have localhost instead of 192.168.0.xxx (your local ip). If that's the case then you need to switch it from localhost to your ip. If this doesn't work then feel free to give me more information (maybe with screenshots or specific network call logs).

You welcome! However I just want to make sure you understand how network and ips work. Basically every machine has a "localhost", so in this case when you were trying to connect through your phone's "localhost/api/data" your phone was looking at itself and trying to access api/data, but obviously this didn't exist. By changing it to your macsIP, your phone was now looking at your computers "/api/data"

Ahaa okey, thank you for taking your time helping and explaining this to me man!!
